# button continually only fire once

Tags: javascript, jquery

If keep clicking the same buttons then only fire once. sample: https://jsfiddle.net/h4wgxofh/, For example, if `click1` clicked then 2nd time or more times clicks should stop firing, the same as `click2` however, if I click the same button, it always fires. Also I want links only trigger once but becomes available if other buttons being clicked. (considering if more buttons) Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Click1</a>
  <a href="#">Click2</a>
</div>
```

Script

```
var clicked = false;

$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
  clicked = true;

  if(clicked = true){
    console.log($this.text());
    clicked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to allow one click for each link, isn't it?

Comment: yes! @AtaurRahmanMunna, should I use `$each`?

Comment: Of course you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something here, but why not just bind the event to every link in .wrap and unbind it on click like this :

```
$('.wrap a').on('click', function(){    
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpnLtpo3/)

Edit : after your comment on wanting one link to be rebound after cliking on another, even though it might not be the cleanest solution, this does the job :

```
var onclick = function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    console.log($el.text());
    $('.wrap a').off('click', onclick);
    $('.wrap a').each(function(id, link){
        if($el.text() != $(link).text())
            $(link).on('click', onclick);
    });
}

$('.wrap a').on('click', onclick);
```

[Fiddle again](https://jsfiddle.net/uyohqynj/)

Comment: thank you `off` is more proper, but after clicking click1, how to make click2 available automatically? so they can't be clicked more than once, but ok to be clicked after click other links

Comment: That's what I wanted. Many thanks :) didn't know `onclick` can be inside itself

Answer (score 1):

See the following code

```js
var clicked1 = false;
var clicked2 = false;

$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
 var $this = $(this);
   var clickOrigin = $(this).text();
 
   if(clickOrigin == 'Click1' && clicked1==false){
        console.log("Click 1 clicked");
        clicked1 = true;
 }
 if(clickOrigin == 'Click2' && clicked2==false){
        console.log("Click 2 clicked");
        clicked2 = true;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Click1</a>
  <a href="#">Click2</a>
</div>
```

Also you can find the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/h4wgxofh/2/).

Comment: thanks a lot, if possible if I `click1`, and then click `click2` , `click1` becomes available to be clicked (fired)? if I have 3 or more buttons. So, which means links can only trigger once but becomes available if clicked other buttons

Comment: For more button, you should use `$(each)` function. In my example if you want to make again link clickable then set corresponding flag false. e.g `clicked1 = false`

Answer (score 1):

You need to Distinguish between two links(i used text here you may put whatever scenario ) see this example it may help:-

```
var clicked1 = 0;
var clicked2 = 0;

$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $text = $(this).text();
  //Click2
  if ($text == 'Click1') {
    clicked1 += 1;
    if (clicked1 == 1) {
      console.log($text);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  //Click2
  if ($text == 'Click2') {
    clicked2 += 1;
    if (clicked2 == 1) {
      console.log($text);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Full [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVaTrJfSbOKRxK2sFwDz?p=preview)

Comment: you can reset the clicked counter to 0 in other button clicks to enable the click again for the relevant anchor (but it will be clickable one time again).

Comment: if you need it to be clickable any time just tell me your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Every time someone clicks one of the buttons, your script is setting clicked from `false` to `true`, checking if the value is `true`, then setting it to `false` again. You need to format it like this if you only want the buttons to fire once (obviously you'd have to duplicate this specifically for each button with different IDs):

```
var clicked = false;

$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  if(clicked == false){
    console.log($this.text());
    clicked = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but once I click `click1`, `click2` doesn't fire, do I have to check each `a`? do I need to use `$each`?

Answer (score 0):

To disable both buttons after first click, try:

```
var clicked = false;

$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
  let $this = $(this);

  if( !clicked ){
    console.log($this.text());
    clicked = true;
  };
});
```

To disable each button after first click, try:

```
$('.wrap a').each(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  $this.disabled = false;
  $this.on('click', function() {
    if ( !$this.disabled ) {
      console.log($this.text());
      $this.disabled = true;
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have links can only trigger once but becomes available if clicked other buttons. considering if have more buttons. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this ,much simpler and this will be more useful if you have multiple click buttons

if you had implemented some other way ,this will worth a try

```
     <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#" data-value="">Click1</a>
      <a href="#" data-value="">Click2</a>
    </div>

    $('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
        var $this = $(this);

      if($this.attr("data-value") == ""){
        console.log($this.text());
        $this.attr("data-value","clicked")
        }
      else{
       console.log("Already clicked")
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4wgxofh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting code on click just on first click disable anchor tag this serve the same thing you wants just find below snippet for more information using this we can reduces round trips to the click functions as well

```js
$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function(){
 $(this).addClass("disableClick");
});
```

```css
.disableClick{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Click1</a>
  <a href="#">Click2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can disable anchor link after one click like this

  <div class="wrap">

  <a href="#" id="click1">Click1</a>

  <a href="#" id="click2">Click2</a>
</div>
```

I think you can disable anchor link after one click like this

```
  <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#" id="click1">Click1</a>
      <a href="#" id="click2">Click2</a>
  </div>
```

```
$(function () {   
$('#click1').on("click", function (e) {
    $('#click1').on("click", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

I think its help you.

Answer (score -3):

Just use `$(".wrap").one('click',` ....

Read the jquery API documentation.

Comment: Don't tell people to read the documentation and not provide a link to the relevant docs.